# Reference from the DocumentClass a movieclip created by an instance of another class

Tags: actionscript-3, document-class

I have this main (document class) in a Flash project:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    public class main extends MovieClip {

        public function main() {
            var other=new Other(this);
        }
    }   
}
```

This one is Other class:

```
    package  {
        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import Clippo;

        public class Other extends MovieClip {
            //
            public function Other(ref) {
                //
                var clippo = new Clippo();
                clippo.name="clippo";
                clippo.x=100;
                clippo.y=100;
                //1
                //ref.addChild(clippo);
                //2
                addChild(clippo);
            }
        }
}
```

Now: if I pass a reference (ref) of the main class to Other and I add clippo as you can see in the first case, I can reference the movieclip clippo from the main (`getChildAt(0)` is "clippo" from the main). But, is there any way to use the second method (no ref) and do the same from the main class? I can see clippo onstage when Other creates it but I can't understand where clippo "lives" into the DisplayList.

Comment: You could add an instance of `Clippo` to the instance of `Other` (like you have) and simply add the instance of `Other` to the instance of `main` like this `var other = new Other(); addChild(other);`. I was going to give this as an answer but I get the feeling that even though your `Other` object is a `MovieClip` object, it was never intended to be used as such, I think you probably extended `MovieClip` when you didn't have to, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish, but:

1. You need to add `other` to the display list if you want to see it or its children.

   ```
   public function main()
   {
       var other:Other = new Other(this);
       addChild(other);
   }
   ```
2. You can use `root` instead of passing a reference to the document class.  (Once it's on the display list).

   ```
   root.addChild(clippo);
   ```

   But, it makes more sense to just add it to Other: `addChild(clippo)`
3. Where you create DisplayObjects doesn't affect the display list, only calling `addChild` does.  Calling `addChild` in the document class, and `root.addChild` in Other result in the same display list.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having this sort of issue, you may need to rethink your architecture.

Make some rules that you follow to make things easier on your self, such as; Don't let child element add children to there parents.

I think the best way to get the reference to your clippo DisplayObject, is to provide a getter method for it.

```
public function get clippo():Clippo
{
    return this.clippo;
}
```